# Is there a way to configure my identity from inside Git-Gui, instead of Git-CMD?

Tags: git-gui

Is there a way to configure my identity from inside Git-Gui, instead of having to go through Git-CMD?

I know how to do it through CMD, as it literally tells you. I'm just wondering if I *need* to use the CMD.

When I tried to merge something with the GUI for the first time, it's asking me to run:

> git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
>
> git config --global user.name "John Doe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least on version `0.21` you can do it by opening a git repository folder then going to `Edit->Option`, then edit your user name and email address in the GUI.